# Lamdba response time different depending on client?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda with an API Gateway trigger that accepts an HTTP POST and returns a JSON response. Runtime is Node.js 12.x.

When I invoke this lambda using the httpie tool (httpie.org), response time is within a second.
When I invoke this lamdda using curl, wget or from chrome (using XMLHttpRequest), response time is around 8 seconds.

AWS Lambda Insights an XRay report the following durations:
With curl, wget or chrome:

- Invocation: 8,44s
- Overhead:    19ms

With httpie.org

- Invocation: 110ms
- Overhead:    57ms

I reproduced the request chrome sends with http using Chrome's 'copy as curl' in the devtools, and posted all the headers using httpie.org